# Parsing arguments and building values

Tags: python, c

I'm integrating my C and Python code. I need send from python an string, "a_string",

```
>>>dicho("a_string")
```

and in my C program below I need receive "a_string" with variable unsigned char *.

```
static PyObject* dicho(PyObject* self, PyObject* args){
unsigned char * cleartext;
PyArg_Parse(args, TYPE, &cleartext);
```

How I will be able to do that? What TYPE need in PyArg_ParseTuple, s,s# ...?

Comment: You can use [`c_char_p`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_char_p)

Comment: @DrewMcGowen thanks by I need unsigned char * and that is only char *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `PyArg_ParseTuple` with the `s#` format. This gives you a `const char *` pointer, which you can cast to `const unsigned char *`.